# Can solve URL DECODE Code?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, restful-url

I am developing android application.I am using RestFull webService.I have encode my url in GET_SEARCH at client side like this

```
    private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            switch (taskType) {
            case POST_TASK:
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                break;
            case GET_SEARCH:
                String restUrl1 = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
                HttpGet httpget1 = new HttpGet(restUrl1);
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget1);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRRORRRRRRR", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Now, I need to decode my URL in my Server Side and my Server side code is like this.

```
@Path("/search")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CustomerEntryDataList getSearchedDetails(
        @QueryParam("cusName") String cusName,
        @QueryParam("compName") String compName,
        @QueryParam("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @QueryParam("endDate") String endDate,
        @QueryParam("status") String status) throws SQLException,
        ParseException {




}
```

Here how can i decode my URL from @QueryParam?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't see no encoding on the Android side, and your server-side code already has decoded the parameters; what is your problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you got wrong the point of URL encoding : you only need to encode URL **parameters** if they contain characters with special meaning within URLs. The most common case is to encode paramaters that contain a URL, so the whole URL can be interpreted without getting mixed up with the embedded URL.